# Break divs of a template into separate templates or use ng-if to show div in the single template with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i am new to angularjs and i need to know which one is the better way to code for the following scenario.

Scenario: i have a single html template with multiple divs and i will be showing only one div at a time based on some condition.

ways i am thinks of:
1.) Should i break the divs into separate small templates and use them in templateURL or 
2.) should i use ng-if to show and hide the required divs in the same single template html.

Note: the individual divs are shown in the modal window.

Please help me know which one is the faster.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If your blocks are rich with html/css and are heavy to render (or if it's large amount of them - hideable rows of a large table for example) - faster would be to use ng-show/ng-hide. It doesn't remove/append elements to DOM, just applies display:none.

If they are relatively simple, you're free to use ng-switch or ng-if.

In your case you want to show only one at time - you can use ng-include with dynamic template name for example. I didn't have any perfomance problems with it.

```
<div ng-include="templateName"></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateOne.html">
   Something
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateOne.html">
   Something another
</script>

$scope.$watchCollection('[condition1, condition2, ...]', function(conditionsArr){
     if(conditionsArr[0] && !conditionsArr[1]){
          $scope.templateName = 'templateOne.html';
     }else{
          $scope.templateName = 'templateTwo.html';
     }
});
```